# Displaying several DIVS when page loads - without hover

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I don't know very much things about javascript/jquery, and I would like to do something :
(excuse for my poor english !)

I would like to make some DIVS appearing step by step without any mouse hover.
I mean : one first div appears in 10 seconds, then the 2nd div appears in 15 seconds, etc..

What do you think about this code ?

It works, but I'm not sure this is very clean :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#firstDiv').hide(0).delay(500).show(400);
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#secondDiv').hide(0).delay(3500).show(400);
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: put both calls in the same function of `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Please try and read about javascript callback that may help in coding in such scenarios

Comment: You can also set the CSS attribute `display: none` on your divs to avoid the initial `.hide(0)` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the elements by css (`display:none;`)

Further, you can put both commands (`.delay().show();`) in the same `document.ready`:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#firstDiv').delay(500).show(400);
        $('#secondDiv').delay(3500).show(400);
    });
</script>
```

Now, for your second request, this will make it have different effects:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#firstDiv').delay(500).fadeIn(400);
        $('#secondDiv').delay(3500).slideIn(400);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much !

Now I'm just wondering.. :)

Is it possible to change the effect ? The way DIV are appearing ?
For example to have a fade effect ? :p